Implementing RBAC Authentication with LDAP Backup in Java Application - Troubleshooting LDAP Availability Check and Pop-Up Message
I am trying to implement RBAC authentication in my application where it should interface with an LDAP server for authentication. I have separate code for logging in using a local database and logging in using LDAP. I am trying to merge the two codes so that when the LDAP server is unavailable, the application switches to authentication using local backup accounts. In my controller, I have the following code snippet:
 @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        if (ldapService.isLdapAvailable()) {
            System.out.println("Inside login method. LDAP is available.");
            return "redirect:/login";  // Redirect to success page if LDAP connection is successful
        } else {
            System.out.println("Inside login method. LDAP is unavailable.");
            model.addAttribute("ldapUnavailableMessage", "LDAP service is currently unavailable. Do you want to continue with local backup authentication?");
            return "login";  // Return login page with an LDAP error message
        }
    }
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String handleLogin(@RequestParam Map<String, String> credentials, HttpSession session, Model model) {
        String username = credentials.get("username");
        String password = credentials.get("password");

        if (ldapService.isLdapAvailable()) {
            // Handle LDAP authentication (not provided in this example)
            System.out.println("LDAP is available and handling login via LDAP.");
            // Assuming LDAP authentication success here for now
            session.setAttribute("username", username);  // Set whatever attributes are needed here
            return "redirect:/dashboard";  // Redirect to dashboard
        } else {
            boolean isAuthenticated = localAuthService.authenticate(username, password);
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                session.setAttribute("username", username);
                System.out.println("Authenticated using local DB.");
                return "redirect:/dashboard";  // Redirect to dashboard or another page
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("error", "Authentication failed. Please check your username and password.");
                System.out.println("Local DB authentication failed.");
                return "login";  // Stay on login page and show error
            }
        }
    }

In my login.html page I am trying something like


<div th:if="${ldapUnavailableMessage}">
        <script>
            alert([[${ldapUnavailableMessage}]]);
            if (confirm("Do you want to continue with local backup authentication?")) {
                window.location.href = "/localLogin"; // Redirect to local login page
            }
        </script>
    </div>



But this isn't working. Code is able to check whether LDAP is available or not. If it is not available it is throwing error
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ldapService'

Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and provide guidance on how to implement the pop-up message for the user in this scenario? Thank you in advance for your help.

Does the error occur at spring startup or when the user tries to log in? Can you please add much more stacktrace to the question?

Dear @JohnWilliams Thank you for your response. I have found that the error occurs at application startup when the LDAP server is not up. I have modified the LDAPconfig class to check if the server is up before trying to connect, and now it is working properly. Thank you for your help. I will answer my question.

I have modified my LdapConfig class as below and then I was able to check at application startup only whether LdapServer is up or not. Sharing here so that it helps other too!
@Configuration
public class LdapConfig {

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${ldap.admin.dn}")
    private String adminDn;

    @Value("${ldap.admin.password}")
    private String adminPassword;
    
    @Value("${ldap.enabled}")
    private boolean ldapEnabled; // to check the property directly
    
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "ldap.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public DirContext ldapContext() throws NamingException {
        
         if(!ldapEnabled) {
             System.out.println("LDAP is not enabled");
             return null;
         }
         
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adminDn);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPassword);

        try {
            DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
            System.out.println("LDAP connection successful.");
            return context;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("LDAP connection failed: ");
            return null; // Rethrow exception to indicate bean creation failed
        }
    }
}

Thank you!
Kailash
